# use of findNodeHandle in react

Tags: reactjs

I recently came across a use-case where I need to measure the components dimensions on runtime. On exploring the solutions I found a tutorial which uses a built in method called **findNodeHandle**. To be precise it was getting used as first argument of measureLayout method.

I tried exploring the use of findNodeHandle but could not find anything.
Can anyone please guide me a little bit on what exactly findNodeHandle does in react.